# GOOGLE MAPS AUTOCOMPLETE state name rather than state code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-geolocation

I am using the google map autocomplete API to allow our customers to search for `city, state, country` formatted locations. Overall it is working well, but the problem is that while I am searching for a city, such as 'Toronto', it will give autocomplete output with abbreviated state names, for example, `Toronto ON, Canada`, as in the image below :

**Example :**

[image]

I want autocomplete output with state name rather than state code.  For example, in the above image, it should instead say `Toronto Ontario, Canada`.

let me give another example : If I search for New York city, it will be output as: `New York, NY, United States`, but instead I would prefer that it be output as `New York, New York, United States`.

Is there some attribute that google provides us with which I could force the state names to be given in full, rather than abbreviated?

I have tried with some work-arounds to fix this issue, but I have so far failed to find a universal, working solution. Can anyone guide me on how best to accomplish this?

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027785/google-maps-autocomplete-get-short-name-for-state-province

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق : I have already reviewed that link, but that is not solution of mine in this above case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing a lot of research on the Google API docs, it seems like the feature you are requesting is not available natively within Google Maps API.

I worked up a work around below that works pretty well. It is a little complicated though, unfortunately.

The first part that is required is a function that loops through an array of international states / provinces with their short name.

JSON formatted international state / province abbreviations found [here](https://github.com/substack/provinces/blob/master/provinces.json)

```
function convertProvince(province, country) {
    
    // Variable containing all the international provinces with their short code
    var provinces = [{short:"AL",name:"Alabama",country:"United States"},{short:"AK",name:"Alaska",country:"United States"},{short:"AZ",name:"Arizona",country:"United States"},{short:"AR",name:"Arkansas",country:"United States"},{short:"CA",name:"California",country:"United States"},{short:"CO",name:"Colorado",country:"United States"},{short:"CT",name:"Connecticut",country:"United States"},{short:"DC",name:["District of Columbia","Washington DC","Washington D.C."],country:"United States"},{short:"DE",name:"Delaware",country:"United States"},{short:"FL",name:"Florida",country:"United States"},{short:"GA",name:"Georgia",country:"United States"},{short:"HI",name:"Hawaii",country:"United States"},{short:"ID",name:"Idaho",country:"United States"},{short:"IL",name:"Illinois",country:"United States"},{short:"IN",name:"Indiana",country:"United States"},{short:"IA",name:"Iowa",country:"United States"},{short:"KS",name:"Kansas",country:"United States"},{short:"KY",name:"Kentucky",country:"United States"},{short:"LA",name:"Louisiana",country:"United States"},{short:"ME",name:"Maine",country:"United States"},{short:"MD",name:"Maryland",country:"United States"},{short:"MA",name:"Massachusetts",country:"United States"},{short:"MI",name:"Michigan",country:"United States"},{short:"MN",name:"Minnesota",country:"United States"},{short:"MS",name:"Mississippi",country:"United States"},{short:"MO",name:"Missouri",country:"United States"},{short:"MT",name:"Montana",country:"United States"},{short:"NE",name:"Nebraska",country:"United States"},{short:"NV",name:"Nevada",country:"United States"},{short:"NH",name:"New Hampshire",country:"United States"},{short:"NJ",name:"New Jersey",country:"United States"},{short:"NM",name:"New Mexico",country:"United States"},{short:"NY",name:"New York",country:"United States"},{short:"NC",name:"North Carolina",country:"United States"},{short:"ND",name:"North Dakota",country:"United States"},{short:"OH",name:"Ohio",country:"United States"},{short:"OK",name:"Oklahoma",country:"United States"},{short:"OR",name:"Oregon",country:"United States"},{short:"PA",name:"Pennsylvania",country:"United States"},{short:"RI",name:"Rhode Island",country:"United States"},{short:"SC",name:"South Carolina",country:"United States"},{short:"SD",name:"South Dakota",country:"United States"},{short:"TN",name:"Tennessee",country:"United States"},{short:"TX",name:"Texas",country:"United States"},{short:"UT",name:"Utah",country:"United States"},{short:"VT",name:"Vermont",country:"United States"},{short:"VA",name:"Virginia",country:"United States"},{short:"WA",name:"Washington",country:"United States"},{short:"WV",name:"West Virginia",country:"United States"},{short:"WI",name:"Wisconsin",country:"United States"},{short:"WY",name:"Wyoming",country:"United States"},{short:"AS",name:"American Samoa",country:"United States"},{short:"GU",name:"Guam",country:"United States"},{short:"MP",name:"Northern Mariana Islands",country:"United States"},{short:"PR",name:"Puerto Rico",country:"United States"},{short:"UM",name:"United States Minor Outlying Islands",country:"United States"},{short:"VI",name:"Virgin Islands",country:"United States"},{short:"AB",name:"Alberta",country:"Canada"},{short:"BC",name:"British Columbia",country:"Canada"},{short:"MB",name:"Manitoba",country:"Canada"},{short:"NB",name:"New Brunswick",country:"Canada"},{short:"NL",name:["Newfoundland and Labrador","Newfoundland","Labrador"],country:"Canada"},{short:"NS",name:"Nova Scotia",country:"Canada"},{short:"NU",name:"Nunavut",country:"Canada"},{short:"NT",name:"Northwest Territories",country:"Canada"},{short:"ON",name:"Ontario",country:"Canada"},{short:"PE",name:"Prince Edward Island",country:"Canada"},{short:"QC",name:"Quebec",country:"Canada"},{short:"SK",name:"Saskatchewan",country:"Canada"},{short:"YT",name:"Yukon",country:"Canada"},{short:"ACT",name:"Australian Capital Territory",country:"Australia"},{short:"CX",name:"Christmas Island",country:"Australia"},{short:"CC",name:"Cocos Islands",alt:["Keeling Islands"],country:"Australia"},{short:"HM",name:"Heard Island and McDonald Islands",country:"Australia"},{short:"JBT",name:"Jervis Bay Territory",country:"Australia"},{short:"NSW",name:"New South Wales",country:"Australia"},{short:"NF",name:"Norfolk Island",country:"Australia"},{short:"NT",name:"Northern Territory",country:"Australia"},{short:"QLD",name:"Queensland",country:"Australia"},{short:"SA",name:"South Australia",country:"Australia"},{short:"TAS",name:"Tasmania",country:"Australia"},{short:"VIC",name:"Victoria",country:"Australia"},{short:"WA",name:"Western Australia",country:"Australia"},{short:"AG",name:"Aguascalientes",alt:["AGS"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"BC",name:"Baja California",alt:["BCN"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"BS",name:"Baja California Sur",alt:["BCS"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"CM",name:"Campeche",alt:["Camp","CAM"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"CS",name:"Chiapas",alt:["Chis","CHP"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"CH",name:"Chihuahua",alt:["Chih","CHH"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"MX",name:"Coahuila",alt:["Coah","COA"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"CL",name:"Colima",alt:["COL"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"DF",name:"Federal District",alt:["DIF"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"DG",name:"Durango",alt:["Dgo","DUR"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"GT",name:"Guanajuato",alt:["Gto","GUA"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"GR",name:"Guerrero",alt:["Gro","GRO"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"HG",name:"Hidalgo",alt:["Hgo","HID"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"JA",name:"Jalisco",alt:["Jal","JAL"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"ME",name:"Mexico",alt:["Edomex","MEX"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"MI",name:"Michoacán",alt:["Mich","MIC"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"MO",name:"Morelos",alt:["Mor","MOR"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"NA",name:"Nayarit",alt:["Nay","NAY"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"NL",name:"Nuevo León",alt:["NLE"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"OA",name:"Oaxaca",alt:["Oax","OAX"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"PU",name:"Puebla",alt:["Pue","PUE"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"QE",name:"Querétaro",alt:["Qro","QUE"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"QR",name:"Quintana Roo",alt:["Q Roo","ROO"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"SL",name:"San Luis Potosí",alt:["SLP"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"SI",name:"Sinaloa",alt:["SIN"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"SO",name:"Sonora",alt:["SON"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"TB",name:"Tabasco",alt:["TAB"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"TM",name:"Tamaulipas",alt:["Tamps","TAM"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"TL",name:"Tlaxcala",alt:["Tlax","TLA"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"VE",name:"Veracruz",alt:["VER"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"YU",name:"Yucatán",alt:["YUC"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"ZA",name:"Zacatecas",alt:["ZAC"],country:"Mexico"},{short:"渝",name:"重庆",english:"Chongqing",country:"China"},{short:"黑",name:"黑龙江",english:"Heilongjiang",country:"China"},{short:"吉",name:"吉林",english:"Jilin",country:"China"},{short:"琼",name:"海南",english:"Hainan",country:"China"},{short:"京",name:"北京",english:"Beijing",country:"China"},{short:"辽",name:"辽宁",english:"Liaoning",country:"China"},{short:"蒙",name:"内蒙古",english:"Inner Mongolia",alt:["Nei Menggu"],country:"China"},{short:"藏",name:"西藏",english:"Xizang",alt:["Tibet"],country:"China"},{short:"青",name:"青海",english:"Qinghai",country:"China"},{short:"宁",name:"宁夏",english:"Ningxia",country:"China"},{short:"新",name:"新疆",english:"Xinjiang",alt:["Uygur"],country:"China"},{short:"甘",name:"甘肃",english:"Gansu",country:"China"},{short:"冀",name:"河北",english:"Hebei",country:"China"},{short:"豫",name:"河南",english:"Henan",country:"China"},{short:"鄂",name:"湖北",english:"Hubei",country:"China"},{short:"湘",name:"湖南",english:"Hunan",country:"China"},{short:"鲁",name:"山东",english:"Shandong",country:"China"},{short:"苏",name:"江苏",english:"Jiangsu",country:"China"},{short:"皖",name:"安徽",english:"Anhui",country:"China"},{short:"晋",name:"山西",english:"Shanxi",country:"China"},{short:"陕",name:"陕西",english:"Shaanxi",country:"China"},{short:"川",name:"四川",english:"sichuan",country:"China"},{short:"滇",name:"云南",english:"Yunnan",country:"China"},{short:"黔",name:"贵州",english:"Guizhou",country:"China"},{short:"浙",name:"浙江",english:"Zhejiang",country:"China"},{short:"闽",name:"福建",english:"Fujian",country:"China"},{short:"桂",name:"广西",english:"Guangxi",country:"China"},{short:"沪",name:"上海",english:"Shanghai",country:"China"},{short:"津",name:"天津",english:"Tianjin",country:"China"},{short:"港",name:"香港",english:"Hongkong",alt:["Hong Kong"],country:"China"},{short:"澳",name:"澳门",english:"Macau",alt:["Macao"],country:"China"},{short:"台",name:"台湾",english:"Taiwan",country:"China"},{short:"赣",name:"江西",english:"Jiangxi",country:"China"},{short:"粤",name:"广东",english:"Guangdong",country:"China"},{short:"BW",name:"Baden-Württemberg",country:"Germany"},{short:"BY",name:"Bayern",country:"Germany"},{short:"BE",name:"Berlin",country:"Germany"},{short:"BB",name:"Brandenburg",country:"Germany"},{short:"HB",name:"Bremen",country:"Germany"},{short:"HH",name:"Hamburg",country:"Germany"},{short:"HE",name:"Hessen",country:"Germany"},{short:"MV",name:"Mecklenburg-Vorpommern",country:"Germany"},{short:"NI",name:"Niedersachsen",country:"Germany"},{short:"NW",name:"Nordrhein-Westfalen",country:"Germany"},{short:"RP",name:"Rheinland-Pfalz",country:"Germany"},{short:"SL",name:"Saarland",country:"Germany"},{short:"SN",name:"Sachsen",country:"Germany"},{short:"ST",name:"Sachsen-Anhalt",country:"Germany"},{short:"SH",name:"Schleswig-Holstein",country:"Germany"},{short:"TH",name:"Thüringen",country:"Germany"},{short:"DR",name:"Drenthe",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"FL",name:"Flevoland",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"FR",name:"Friesland",country:"Netherlands",alt:["Fryslân"]},{short:"GD",name:"Gelderland",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"GR",name:"Groningen",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"LB",name:"Limburg",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"NB",name:"Noord-Brabant",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"NH",name:"Noord-Holland",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"OV",name:"Overijssel",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"UT",name:"Utrecht",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"ZH",name:"Zuid-Holland",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"ZL",name:"Zeeland",country:"Netherlands"},{short:"ANT",name:"Antwerpen",country:"Belgium"},{short:"HAI",name:"Henegouwen",country:"Belgium",alt:["Hainaut"]},{short:"LIE",name:"Luik",country:"Belgium",alt:["Liège"]},{short:"LIM",name:"Limburg",country:"Belgium"},{short:"LUX",name:"Luxemburg",country:"Belgium"},{short:"NAM",name:"Namen",country:"Belgium"},{short:"OVL",name:"Oost-Vlaanderen",country:"Belgium"},{short:"VBR",name:"Vlaams-Brabant",country:"Belgium"},{short:"WBR",name:"Waals-Brabant",country:"Belgium"},{short:"WVL",name:"West-Vlaanderen",country:"Belgium"},{short:"ID-AC",name:"Special Region of Aceh",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-BA",name:"Bali",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-BB",name:"Bangka–Belitung Islands",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-BT",name:"Banten",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-BE",name:"Bengkulu",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-JT",name:"Central Java",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-KT",name:"Central Kalimantan",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-ST",name:"Central Sulawesi",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-JI",name:"East Java",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-KI",name:"East Kalimantan",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-NT",name:"East Nusa Tenggara",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-GO",name:"Gorontalo",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-JK",name:"Jakarta Special Capital Region",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-JA",name:"Jambi",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-LA",name:"Lampung",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-MA",name:"Maluku",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-KU",name:"North Kalimantan",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-MU",name:"North Maluku",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-SA",name:"North Sulawesi",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-SU",name:"North Sumatra",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-PA",name:"Special Region of Papua",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-RI",name:"Riau",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-KR",name:"Riau Islands",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-SG",name:"Southeast Sulawesi",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-KS",name:"South Kalimantan",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-SN",name:"South Sulawesi",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-SS",name:"South Sumatra",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-JB",name:"West Java",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-KB",name:"West Kalimantan",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-NB",name:"West Nusa Tenggara",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-PB",name:"Special Region of West Papua",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-SR",name:"West Sulawesi",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-SB",name:"West Sumatra",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"ID-YO",name:"Special Region of Yogyakarta",country:"Indonesia"},{short:"AP",name:"Andhra Pradesh",country:"India"},{short:"AR",name:"Arunachal Pradesh",country:"India"},{short:"AS",name:"Assam",country:"India"},{short:"BR",name:"Bihar",country:"India"},{short:"CT",name:"Chhattisgarh",country:"India"},{short:"GA",name:"Goa",country:"India"},{short:"GJ",name:"Gujarat",country:"India"},{short:"HR",name:"Haryana",country:"India"},{short:"HP",name:"Himachal Pradesh",country:"India"},{short:"JK",name:"Jammu and Kashmir",country:"India"},{short:"JH",name:"Jharkhand",country:"India"},{short:"KA",name:"Karnataka",country:"India"},{short:"KL",name:"Kerala",country:"India"},{short:"MP",name:"Madhya Pradesh",country:"India"},{short:"MH",name:"Maharashtra",country:"India"},{short:"MN",name:"Manipur",country:"India"},{short:"ML",name:"Meghalaya",country:"India"},{short:"MZ",name:"Mizoram",country:"India"},{short:"NL",name:"Nagaland",country:"India"},{short:"OR",name:"Odisha",country:"India"},{short:"PB",name:"Punjab",country:"India"},{short:"RJ",name:"Rajasthan",country:"India"},{short:"SK",name:"Sikkim",country:"India"},{short:"TN",name:"Tamil Nadu",country:"India"},{short:"TG",name:"Telangana",country:"India"},{short:"TR",name:"Tripura",country:"India"},{short:"UP",name:"Uttar Pradesh",country:"India"},{short:"UT",name:"Uttarakhand",country:"India"},{short:"WB",name:"West Bengal",country:"India"},{short:"AN",name:"Andaman and Nicobar Islands",country:"India"},{short:"CH",name:"Chandigarh",country:"India"},{short:"DN",name:"Dadra and Nagar Haveli",country:"India"},{short:"DD",name:"Daman and Diu",country:"India"},{short:"LD",name:"Lakshadweep",country:"India"},{short:"DL",name:"National Capital Territory of Delhi",country:"India"},{short:"PY",name:"Puducherry",country:"India"},{short:"C",name:"La Coruña",country:"Spain"},{short:"LU",name:"Lugo",country:"Spain"},{short:"BI",name:"Vizcaya",country:"Spain"},{short:"SS",name:"Guipúzcoa",country:"Spain"},{short:"HU",name:"Huesca",country:"Spain"},{short:"L",name:"Lérida",country:"Spain"},{short:"GI",name:"Gerona",country:"Spain"},{short:"B",name:"Barcelona",country:"Spain"},{short:"T",name:"Tarragona",country:"Spain"},{short:"CS",name:"Castellón",country:"Spain"},{short:"V",name:"Valencia",country:"Spain"},{short:"A",name:"Alicante",country:"Spain"},{short:"MU",name:"Murcia",country:"Spain"},{short:"Z",name:"Zaragoza",country:"Spain"},{short:"TE",name:"Teruel",country:"Spain"},{short:"CU",name:"Cuenca",country:"Spain"},{short:"AB",name:"Albacete",country:"Spain"},{short:"AL",name:"Almeria",country:"Spain"},{short:"GR",name:"Granada",country:"Spain"},{short:"MA",name:"Málaga",country:"Spain"},{short:"TF",name:"Tenerife",country:"Spain"},{short:"CA",name:"Cádiz",country:"Spain"},{short:"SE",name:"Sevilla",country:"Spain"},{short:"H",name:"Huelva",country:"Spain"},{short:"GC",name:"Las Palmas",country:"Spain"},{short:"M",name:"Madrid",country:"Spain"},{short:"BA",name:"Badajoz",country:"Spain"},{short:"CC",name:"Cáceres",country:"Spain"},{short:"TO",name:"Toledo",country:"Spain"},{short:"CR",name:"Ciudad Real",country:"Spain"},{short:"SA",name:"Salamanca",country:"Spain"},{short:"CO",name:"Córdoba",country:"Spain"},{short:"J",name:"Jaén",country:"Spain"},{short:"AV",name:"Ávila",country:"Spain"},{short:"VA",name:"Valladolid",country:"Spain"},{short:"ZA",name:"Zamora",country:"Spain"},{short:"VI",name:"Álava",country:"Spain"},{short:"SG",name:"Segovia",country:"Spain"},{short:"BU",name:"Burgos",country:"Spain"},{short:"PO",name:"Pontevedra",country:"Spain"},{short:"LE",name:"León",country:"Spain"},{short:"OU",name:"Orense",country:"Spain"},{short:"P",name:"Palencia",country:"Spain"},{short:"LO",name:"La Rioja",country:"Spain"},{short:"SO",name:"Soria",country:"Spain"},{short:"GU",name:"Guadalajara",country:"Spain"},{short:"AB",name:"Abia",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"FC",name:"Abuja",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"AD",name:"Adamawa",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"AK",name:"Akwa Ibom",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"AN",name:"Anambra",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"BA",name:"Bauchi",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"BY",name:"Bayelsa",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"BE",name:"Benue",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"BO",name:"Borno",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"CR",name:"Cross River",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"DE",name:"Delta",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"EB",name:"Ebonyi",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"ED",name:"Edo",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"EK",name:"Ekiti",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"EN",name:"Enugu",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"GO",name:"Gombe",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"IM",name:"Imo",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"JI",name:"Jigawa",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"KD",name:"Kaduna",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"KN",name:"Kano",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"KT",name:"Katsina",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"KE",name:"Kebbi",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"KO",name:"Kogi",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"KW",name:"Kwara",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"LA",name:"Lagos",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"NA",name:"Nasarawa",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"NI",name:"Niger",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"OG",name:"Ogun",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"ON",name:"Ondo",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"OS",name:"Osun",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"OY",name:"Oyo",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"PL",name:"Plateau",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"RI",name:"Rivers",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"SO",name:"Sokoto",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"TA",name:"Taraba",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"YO",name:"Yobe",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"ZA",name:"Zamfara",country:"Nigeria"},{short:"B",name:"Burgenland",country:"Austria"},{short:"K",name:"Kärnten",country:"Austria"},{short:"NÖ",name:"Niederösterreich",country:"Austria"},{short:"OÖ",name:"Oberösterreich",country:"Austria"},{short:"S",name:"Salzburg",country:"Austria"},{short:"ST",name:"Steiermark",country:"Austria"},{short:"T",name:"Tirol",country:"Austria"},{short:"V",name:"Vorarlberg",country:"Austria"},{short:"W",name:"Wien",country:"Austria"},{short:"AC",name:"Acre",country:"Brazil"},{short:"AL",name:"Alagoas",country:"Brazil"},{short:"AP",name:"Amapá",country:"Brazil"},{short:"AM",name:"Amazonas",country:"Brazil"},{short:"BA",name:"Bahia",country:"Brazil"},{short:"CE",name:"Ceará",country:"Brazil"},{short:"DF",name:"Distrito Federal",country:"Brazil"},{short:"ES",name:"Espírito Santo",country:"Brazil"},{short:"GO",name:"Goiás",country:"Brazil"},{short:"MA",name:"Maranhão",country:"Brazil"},{short:"MT",name:"Mato Grosso",country:"Brazil"},{short:"MS",name:"Mato Grosso do Sul",country:"Brazil"},{short:"MG",name:"Minas Gerais",country:"Brazil"},{short:"PA",name:"Pará",country:"Brazil"},{short:"PB",name:"Paraíba",country:"Brazil"},{short:"PR",name:"Paraná",country:"Brazil"},{short:"PE",name:"Pernambuco",country:"Brazil"},{short:"PI",name:"Piauí",country:"Brazil"},{short:"RJ",name:"Rio de Janeiro",country:"Brazil"},{short:"RN",name:"Rio Grande do Norte",country:"Brazil"},{short:"RS",name:"Rio Grande do Sul",country:"Brazil"},{short:"RO",name:"Rondônia",country:"Brazil"},{short:"RR",name:"Roraima",country:"Brazil"},{short:"SC",name:"Santa Catarina",country:"Brazil"},{short:"SP",name:"São Paulo",country:"Brazil"},{short:"SE",name:"Sergipe",country:"Brazil"},{short:"TO",name:"Tocantins",country:"Brazil"}];

    // Loop through all the available provinces
    for (var i = provinces.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        // Check if the name is an array (e.g. alternative names)
        if (Array.isArray(provinces[i].name)) {
        
            // If the province name 1st item matches the given one, return the abbreviation
            if (provinces[i].name[0].toUpperCase() == province.toUpperCase() && provinces[i].country.toUpperCase() == country.toUpperCase()) {
            
                return provinces[i].short;
            
            }
        
        }

        else {

            // If the province abbreviation matches the current one, return the full province name
            if (provinces[i].short.toUpperCase() == province.toUpperCase() && provinces[i].country.toUpperCase() == country.toUpperCase()){

                return provinces[i].name;

            }

            // If the province name matches the given one, return the abbreviation
            if (provinces[i].name.toUpperCase() == province.toUpperCase && provinces[i].country.toUpperCase() == country.toUpperCase()) {
            
                return provinces[i].short;
            
            }

        }

    }

    // Default return if no province found
    return "";
}
```

Main function that attaches the Google Maps Autocomplete API to the input field.

```
var init = function() {

        // Input element where the searches will be entered
    var input                   = document.getElementById('search'),

        // Create a new Google Autocomplete object
        autocomplete            = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService(),

        // Div element where the prediction will be inserted
        predictions_container   = document.getElementById("google_predictions"),

        // Variable to control the Timeout delay when user enters text
        searchWait;

        // Add the keyup event listener to the input element
    input.addEventListener('keyup', function() {

        // Only run the autocomplete if the input field has text in it
        if (this.value.length === 0) {

            // Reset the container of the autocomplete predictions
            predictions_container.innerHTML = "";

            return;

        }

        // First clear the timeout before setting a new one
        clearTimeout(searchWait);

        // Create the delayed function to activate the Google Autocomplete function
        // searchValue = the value of the input field
        searchWait = setTimeout(function(searchValue) {

            return function() {

                // Create a new event listener for when we receive the results from Google
                autocomplete.getPlacePredictions({input: searchValue}, function(predictions, status) {

                    // Only proceed if Google says it's all good
                    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

                        // Variable that will contain the HTML to be put into the prediction
                        // container div
                        var newHTML = "";

                        // Loop through each of the predictions sent from Google
                        for (var i = predictions.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                            // Regex to find the state abbreviation
                            var provincePattern         = /,\s[A-Z]{1,2},/,

                                // Regex to find the country
                                countryPattern          = /,\s[A-Za-z\s]{1,}$/,

                                // Get the prediction text
                                predictionText          = predictions[i].description;

                            // If the prediction has a province abbreviation continue
                            if (provincePattern.test(predictionText)) {

                                // Get the abbreviated form of the province / state
                                var province = predictionText.match(provincePattern)[0];

                                // Get the country, and remove the preceeding comma and space
                                var country = predictionText.match(countryPattern)[0].slice(2);

                                // Remove the trailing comma
                                province = province.substring(0, province.length-1)

                                // Remove any extra commas or whitespace
                                province = province.replace(/[,|\s]/g, "");

                                // Replace the abbreviated province / state with with the full name of the province / state
                                // and add a comma before and after to correct the styling
                                var predictionText = predictionText.replace(provincePattern, ", " + convertProvince(province, country) + ",");

                                // ------------------------------------
                                // HERE'S THE CONVERTED PREDICTED TEXT
                                // ------------------------------------
                                // predictionText = each row of the predicted results sent from Google
                                console.log(predictionText);

                            }

                            // Create a new prediction row
                            var newRow = "<div class='prediction_rows'>" + predictionText + "</div>";

                            // New HTML to insert into the predictions container
                            newHTML = newHTML + newRow;

                        }

                        // Insert the new HTML into the predictions container
                        predictions_container.innerHTML = newHTML + "<img style='float: right' width='100' src='https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/images/powered-by-google-on-white.png' />";

                    }

                });

            }

        } (this.value), 500);

    });
}


init();
```

Main HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<input type="text" id="search" name="search" placeholder="search google places" style="width: 500px; margin-top: 50px;" autofocus>

<div class="predictions" id="google_predictions" style="width: 500px;">



</div>
```

I also made a quick little jQuery plugin to accomplish this as well, which can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/rootr/GoogleAutocomplete.jQuery)

Using the jQuery plugin you can implement it like so:

```
$("#ID_OF_INPUT_FIELD").addressAutocomplete();
```

Comment: Thanks Man, but this is not a universal solution, what about future if new state will come?

Comment: @Jigar7521 You're going to have to do some sort of lookup. If you don't want to hard code it, your other option is to make use of an API that does this sort of thing. Although it will probably slow down your app a bit, and you might need to pay for it. This API allows you to enter the country and province code, to get full details including the name: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/api/provinces.html or you can use this fusion table through REST: https://fusiontables.google.com/DataSource?docid=19lLpgsKdJRHL2O4fNmJ406ri9JtpIIk8a-AchA#card:id=2

Comment: @rootr : Ok now it seems like working, will see and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Can I have a demo please? like jsfiddle or something? because It is not integrating at my side.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Google Places autocomplete`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) may be more appropriate for your needs (as opposed to using an address box). There is sample code in the link to the google docs link provided which I saved in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/ejo95dLf/).

If you wanted to extend it a bit, there are other options suggested in the [Google Maps API docs [for Autocomplete]](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete) such as [adding route](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions) possibilities/directions ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/gxnfbqoz/)).

Alternatively, you could just add a more simple [search box](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/x321500r/) that would autocomplete (without the options/title etc.)

Code for Autocomplete (with options):

```js
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });
  var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
  var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

  // Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
  // so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
  // bounds option in the request.
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
      // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
      window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    if (place.address_components) {
      address = [
        (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
        (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
      ].join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });

  // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
  // Autocomplete.
  function setupClickListener(id, types) {
    var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
    radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      autocomplete.setTypes(types);
    });
  }

  setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
  setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
  setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);

  document.getElementById('use-strict-bounds')
      .addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log('Checkbox clicked! New state=' + this.checked);
        autocomplete.setOptions({strictBounds: this.checked});
      });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#description {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#infowindow-content .title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#infowindow-content {
  display: none;
}

#map #infowindow-content {
  display: inline;
}

.pac-card {
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#pac-container {
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.pac-controls {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 11px;
}

.pac-controls label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 400px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

#title {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 6px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div>
    <div id="title">
      Autocomplete search
    </div>
    <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" checked="checked">
      <label for="changetype-all">All</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
      <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
      <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

      <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
      <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
    </div>
    <div id="strict-bounds-selector" class="pac-controls">
      <input type="checkbox" id="use-strict-bounds" value="">
      <label for="use-strict-bounds">Strict Bounds</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text"
        placeholder="Enter a location">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
  <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
  <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you need to enter your own API key for the snippet to work i think

Comment: Thanks, but this is no a solution I was looking for :(

Comment: solution which I am looking for is simple as : e.g if i will write 'New york' in search box then it will return from google like : 'New York, NY, United state' and I want that should be converted to the string like : 'New York, New York, United state' , in case of 'NY' state short name, same for all like 'ON' for ontario and etc.
I just need this string in variable on selection from return result of google dropdown.

Comment: @Jigar7521 why do you have your dropdown configured like so then? That's how USA formats it's addresses. You can return New York, United States or New York , NY, United States - both are available options in Google Maps. But you can't force user selection (or change how people use addresses). Either write some more js yourself or re-configure your dropdown. (latter is easier!)

Comment: yes you are right, I thought I have to work around there, any way, thanks but.

Comment: There is away that we can grab out state short name and long name from selection event from drop down on select. I just want to assign it in js variable.

Comment: @Jigar7521 I only saw the last two comments today (and only because I revisited the question) .. learn to use the '@' symbol ; that way your messages will be delivered to my inbox and i will see them.